# Internal Circuitry of OP Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

Do i need to worry about internal circuitry of OP-Amp?
PLs suggest me a good book to study about op amp

Comment: No, you don't need to worry about the internal circuitry of an op amp. Stay out of the swamp and on the interstate.

Answer (score 4):

No, not really.  *How* it works can be useful for understanding or to satisfy curiosity, but in the end you can design circuits with these things solely from the *what it does* information in the datasheet.  In fact, you often have to be careful to not make assumptions about what it does from how you think it works.  How you *think* it works can be different enough in detail from how it actually works, that basing a design on that can get you into trouble.  Also, the details of how it works can change subtly between revisions.  If it's not in the datasheet, then you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

In the main the data sheet is the best information available but there are subtleties about the internals of some op-amps that are worth remembering. In particular (and one that caught me out once), some op-amps internally have clamp diodes across the inverting and non-inverting inputs and if you try to use the op-amp as a comparator you don't get the results you planned on. The only real hint that these might be there is in the absolute maximum ratings in the data sheet where max differential voltage is specified probably at about +/-1V or so.

It helps to have a little bit of knowledge beyond treating the data sheet as a black-box specification.

Comment: Despite what I said, I do agree with this, but only if you really know what you're doing. Those that are less than expert-level EEs will get into more trouble thinking they know how something works inside than it will help them. Even those that do know what they are doing have to be very careful how they apply assumptions about how things work inside.